# Create a data.frame with all transition counts

Tags: r, dataframe

Assume a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a","b","c","d","e"),rank = c(1,1,4,3,2))


   name rank
    a    1
    b    1
    c    4
    d    3
    e    2
```

Based on the above data.frame, I want to create a new one that holds the count of transitions from one rank to another. So the output would be something like this:

```
  name 1to1 1to2 1to3 1to4 2to1 2to2 2to3 2to4 3to1 3to2 3to3 3to4 4to1 4to2 4to3 4to4
1    b    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2    c   NA   NA   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3    d   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA
4    e   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

One way to do this would be to run a `for` loop and then using `ifs` but I am pretty sure there should be a more efficient way of doing this.

For example, if item `d` has a rank of `3` and item `c` is ranked as `4` then the code should increase the count of the `4to3` column under `d`'s row (as per example above). Please let me know if this is unclear and I appreciate all the help.

P.S. colnames are not that important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Map` to create `seq`uences for extracting the transitions and collapse them into the desired form using `paste`.

```
tmp <- sapply(Map(seq, 1:(nrow(df1)-1), 2:nrow(df1)), function(i) df1$rank[i])
v <- apply(tmp, 2, function(x) paste(x, collapse="to"))
```

Then create a grid with all permutations

```
to <- apply(expand.grid(1:4, 1:4), 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse="to"))
```

and compare them with the actual transitions to get the resulting binary structure; create a data frame out of it.

```
res <- data.frame(name=df1$name[-1], t(sapply(v, function(i) setNames(+(i == to), to))))
```

Afterwards, you may convert the zeroes to `NA` using

```
res[res == 0] <- NA
```

#### Result

```
res
#      name X1to1 X2to1 X3to1 X4to1 X1to2 X2to2 X3to2 X4to2 X1to3 X2to3 X3to3 X4to3 X1to4 X2to4 X3to4 X4to4
# 1to1    b     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 1to4    c    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA    NA    NA
# 4to3    d    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 3to2    e    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

---

*Data*

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e"), class = "factor"), rank = c(1, 1, 4, 3, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: ahhh! That does the trick! Thanks for spotting jay.sf! `df$rank[i]` in your example needs to be changed to `df1$rank[i]` to work with your data structure but this works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @Maylo Thanks for the errata! I used `df1` because `df` is already a defined function in R.